# L1 distance between categorical distribution and any arbitrary estimator?

Tags: distributions, distance, estimators

Given an unknown categorical distribution $p$ over $k$ categories, and any arbitrary estimator of this distribution vector $q$ constructed from $n$ i.i.d samples, can anyone point me to some results on upper bounds for the L1 distance between $p$ and $q$, $\sum_{i\in{k}}{|p(i)-q(i)|}$?

By arbitrary estimator I mean that it's not important to me which estimator is used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a result of the form $P(d_{TV}(p,q) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_k |p(k) - q(k)| > \epsilon) < f(n,\epsilon)$. If your estimator is the empirical distribution, then there are general results about the convergence of the empirical to the true distribution, e.g. Van der Vaart, Aad W. Asymptotic statistics. Vol. 3. Cambridge university press, 2000.

It looks to be hard to find something of this form completely specific to categorical data, but for an analysis of confidence set coverage for such data that uses total variation/L1 distance, see page 440 of [Beran, R., and P. W. Millar. "Confidence sets for a multivariate distribution." The Annals of Statistics (1986): 431-443.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2241228.pdf?casa_token=Dj9kXXjnIekAAAAA:TebFyJDZAJNEUkec2uIfCHykKWmy3kc5OMawTq5FTV_P5vw68sGk_Xk2mjj9y8cCo7yxDhnbJkPYa2MuWIq-ObTeIkbXJIvKNkq0Y-WtJWl_lBg-IT4)